# Setting up the **second** leader key for Xah-Fly-Keys

Tags: key-bindings

Inspired by [this post](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/xah-fly-keys_kinesis_config.html), I tried to set up a second leader key for my `Xah-Fly-Keys` for major mode commands (as suggested in the post). But I couldn't find how I can set up the **second** leader key for `Xah-Fly-Keys`. I also ask this question in Xah-Fly-Keys [Reddit forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/xahflykeys/comments/bcwt54/setting_up_the_leader_key_for_major_modes_commands/) but didn't get any answer. Does anyone know how?

In case you wonder why I'm trying to that: The purpose is using a single key binding for similar actions in different major-modes. For example, running a unit of code (e.g. a source block in org-mode, a cell in matlab-mode and etc) with e.g.  + RET (note that  is the "second leader key" suggested by the post I mentioned). I propose a solution in [Reddit forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/xahflykeys/comments/bcwt54/setting_up_the_leader_key_for_major_modes_commands/), but with using the control key (rather a new leader key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one needs introduce `<deletechar>` to command mode of xah-fly-keys (XFK):

```
(defun ss-xfk-addon-command()
  "Modify keys for xah fly key command mode keys
To be added to `xah-fly-insert-mode-activate-hook'"
  (interactive)
  (define-key xah-fly-key-map (kbd "<deletechar>") 'ss-xfk-delchar-keymap)
  ;; more here
  )
```

Then add the needed keybindings; For example this is a piece from my config:

```
(xah-fly--define-keys
 (define-prefix-command 'ss-xfk-delchar-keymap)
 '(
   ("a" . eshell-command)

   ("c" . increment-number-at-point) ; i
   ("t" . decrement-number-at-point) ; k

   ("." . org-edit-special) ; e

   ("RET" . ss-run-code-unit)
   ("n" . read-only-mode) ; l

   ("v" . flyspell-auto-correct-word) ; .
   ("w" . flyspell-goto-next-error) ; ,

   ("e" . goto-line) ; d

   )
 )
```

and then let then, let XFK add them to the command mode:

```
(add-hook 'xah-fly-command-mode-activate-hook 'ss-xfk-addon-command)
```